# I am not able to start react scripts

Tags: reactjs, npm

**I want to create react app using create-react-app .**
I have done `npx create-react-app tushar` and when i want to run it using `npm start` .
It is showing errors .

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle tushar@0.1.0~prestart: tushar@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle tushar@0.1.0~start: tushar@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle tushar@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle tushar@0.1.0~start: PATH: D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Users\PIRATES\Desktop\reacttut\tushar\node_modules\.bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin;D:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin;D:\Users\PIRATES\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\Program Files\nodejs
9 verbose lifecycle tushar@0.1.0~start: CWD: D:\Users\PIRATES\Desktop\reacttut\tushar
10 silly lifecycle tushar@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle tushar@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle tushar@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: tushar@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid tushar@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\Users\PIRATES\Desktop\reacttut\tushar
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.2.9200
17 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error tushar@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the tushar@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

***I have search many post but i could not find solution***
My JSON file

```
{
  "name": "tushar",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**They were showing to do npm audit , after npm audit it was showing **

```
                       === npm audit security report ===

                                 Manual Review
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance

  Low             Prototype Pollution
  Package         yargs-parser

  Patched in      >=13.1.2 <14.0.0 || >=15.0.1 <16.0.0 || >=18.1.2

  Dependency of   react-scripts
  Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > yargs > yargs-parser
  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500
found 1 low severity vulnerability in 1665 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.

D:\Users\PIRATES\Desktop\reacttut\tushar>
```

I don't know  many muchabout react coz i have started learning today.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution on DEV i am using windows and i adde `%SystemRoot%\system32` to my path variable and it worked .